# Проблемы с запуском dll

Tags: c++-cli

В программе должна появляться кнопка при нажатии на которую выведется сообщение "TEST". Но кнопка просто не появляется но при этом ошибок при билдинге нет
и я не могу зайти в код проекта к которому подсоеденяется dll я должен закинуть dll в корневую папку и суть в том что такая же dll только на c# работает просто нужно на c++/cli

1 файл

```
#pragma region Usings
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;


#pragma endregion

namespace RGiesecke
{
    namespace DllExport
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Used to control how to create an unmanaged export for a static method.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// You are not bound to using this class in this assembly.
        /// By default, any attribute named "RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportAttribute.DllExportAttribute" will do the trick.
        /// Even if it is declared to be only visible inside the assembly with the static methods you want to export.
        /// In such a case the naming and typing of the fileds/properties is critical or otherwise the provided values will not be used.
        /// </remarks>
        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets::Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
        private ref class DllExportAttribute : Attribute
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DllExportAttribute"/> class.
            /// </summary>
        public:
            DllExportAttribute()
            {
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DllExportAttribute"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="exportName">Name of the unmanaged export.
            /// <seealso cref="ExportName"/></param>
            DllExportAttribute(String ^exportName) //: DllExportAttribute(exportName, System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention::StdCall)


            {


            }


            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DllExportAttribute"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="exportName">Name of the unmanaged export.
            /// <seealso cref="ExportName"/></param>
            /// <param name="callingConvention">The calling convention of the unmanaged .
            /// <seealso cref="CallingConvention"/></param>
            DllExportAttribute(String ^exportName,  System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention callingConvention)
            {

                ExportName = exportName;
                CallingConvention = callingConvention;
            }

        private:
            static  System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention CConv = safe_cast< System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention>(0);


            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the calling convention that will be used by the unmanaged export.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The calling convention.</value>
        public:
            property  System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention CallingConvention
            {
                 System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention get()
                {
                    return CConv;
                }
                void set( System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention value)
                {
                    CConv = value;
                }
            }

        private:
            String ^ExpName;

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets or sets the name of the unmanaged export.
            /// </summary>
            /// <value>The name of the export.</value>
        public:
            property String ^ExportName
            {
                String ^get()
                {
                    return ExpName;
                }
                void set(String ^value)
                {
                    ExpName = value;
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

2 файл

```
// ISHDAN.h

#pragma once
#include "DllExport\RGiesecke.DllExport.DllExportAttribute.h"

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace RGiesecke::DllExport;
namespace Class2 {

    public ref class Class1
    {

        [DllExport("ISHDAN", CallingConvention = System::Runtime::InteropServices::CallingConvention::Cdecl)]
        double static ISHDAN(String ^connTemp, String ^connEoi, String ^cex, String ^SV, String ^SO, String ^izd, String ^TP, String ^cher)
        {
            MessageBox::Show("TEST");
          return 1;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Странно, но из вопроса вообще ничего не понял, что вы делаете и зачем?

Comment: Перевёл dllку из c# в c++/cli но она не работает при этом норм собирается

Comment: А какой в этом смысл? И что это за атрибут `DllExport`?

Comment: Да мне на работе сказали сделать и все

Comment: Я задам тот же вопрос, что и на en.so: _должна появляться кнопка_ - какая кнопка? В вашем коде я не вижу никаких кнопок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov кнопка в готовой программе куда надо закинуть dll, dll написаная на c# работает надо что бы работало на c++cli

Comment: _кнопка просто не появляется_ - у вас проблема с кодом на C#, показывающим кнопку? Или с чем?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov проблема с dll написаной на c++cli которая перед вами точно такая же dll только на c# работает, в программе есть кнопка за которую эта dll отвечает и с dll на c# есть кнопка все работает а вот с кодом который перед вами кнопки бросто нет хотя dll собирается без ошибок

Comment: _кнопки нет_ - это не проблема показанного кода на c++/cli. Если кнопка создана и показывается кодом на c#, то разбирайтесь с кодом на c#.